# Upload the datasets into Shiny(from PC) and the possibility to choose them in sidebar panel

Tags: r, shiny

I want to upload 4 datasets into shiny and i want to create for the users the possibility to choose between these 4 datasets(sidebar panel):

```
ui <- sidebarPanel(
    headerPanel('BTYDplus package: MLE estimation'),
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput('Data','Select the dataset',choices = c('CDNOW','Dietary','Office','Grocery','Donations','M18'))
    ),
    mainPanel(
        h4('Log-Likelihood'),
        verbatimTextOutput('param_est'),

        h4('Transactions in Holdout period'),
        tableOutput('trans_hold_out'),

        h4('Estimation P(alive)'),
        tableOutput('p_alive'),

        h4('Comparison Forecasting Accuracy'),
        tableOutput('forecasting')
    )
)

server <- function(input,output){
    d <- reactive({
        if(input$Data == 'CDNOW'){
            elog <- data.table(read.csv(file = 'cdnow_elog.csv', stringsAsFactors = F))        
            elog <- elog[, date := as.Date(date, '%Y-%m-%d')]
            elog <- elog[, first := min(date), by='cust']
            cbs <- elog2cbs(elog, per = 'week', T.cal = as.Date('1997-09-30'))
        }else if(input$Data == 'Dietary'){
            elog <- data.table(read.csv(file = 'dietary-elog.csv', stringsAsFactors = F))
            cbs <- elog2cbs(elog, T.cal = as.Date('2014-09-01'))
        }else if(input$Data == 'Grocery'){
            elog <- data.table(read.csv(file = 'grocery-elog.csv', stringsAsFactors = F))
            cbs <- elog2cbs(elog, T.cal = as.Date('2006-12-31'), T.tot = as.Date('2007-12-31'))
        }else if(input$Data == 'M18'){
            elog <- data.table(read.csv(file = 'm18-elog.csv', stringsAsFactors = F))
            cbs <- elog2cbs(elog, per = 'week', T.cal = as.Date('2009-12-31'), T.tot = as.Date('2010-03-31'))
        }
    )}
```

To be honest, i don't know how to do it correctly(I did it intuitively), but i didn't find such examples on Stackoverflow or on shiny web-page

Moreover i have got such an error:

```
Error: unexpected ')' in:
"        }
    )"
```

How can i solve this two problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're doing it fine but you had wrong order of closing brackets of `reactive`. You also want to return `cbs`. I also modified your `ui` - added `fluidPage`, wrapped `sidebarPanel` and `mainPanel` into `sidebarLayout` and moved `headerPanel`.

---

**Full example:**

```
library(data.table)

ui <- fluidPage( #added fluidPage
  headerPanel('BTYDplus package: MLE estimation'),  # moved headerPanel 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('Data','Select the dataset',choices = c('CDNOW','Dietary','Office','Grocery','Donations','M18'))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h4('Log-Likelihood'),
      verbatimTextOutput('param_est'),

      h4('Transactions in Holdout period'),
      tableOutput('trans_hold_out'),

      h4('Estimation P(alive)'),
      tableOutput('p_alive'),

      h4('Comparison Forecasting Accuracy'),
      tableOutput('forecasting')
    )#end mainPanel
  )#end sidebarLayout
)#end fluidPage

server <- function(input,output) {

  d <- reactive({

    if(input$Data == 'CDNOW') {
      print("a")
      elog <- data.table(read.csv(file = 'cdnow_elog.csv', stringsAsFactors = F))
      elog <- elog[, date := as.Date(date, '%Y-%m-%d')]
      elog <- elog[, first := min(date), by='cust']
      cbs <- elog2cbs(elog, per = 'week', T.cal = as.Date('1997-09-30'))

    } else if(input$Data == 'Dietary') {
      elog <- data.table(read.csv(file = 'dietary-elog.csv', stringsAsFactors = F))
      cbs <- elog2cbs(elog, T.cal = as.Date('2014-09-01'))

    } else if(input$Data == 'Grocery') {
      elog <- data.table(read.csv(file = 'grocery-elog.csv', stringsAsFactors = F))
      cbs <- elog2cbs(elog, T.cal = as.Date('2006-12-31'), T.tot = as.Date('2007-12-31'))

    } else if(input$Data == 'M18') {
      elog <- data.table(read.csv(file = 'm18-elog.csv', stringsAsFactors = F))
      cbs <- elog2cbs(elog, per = 'week', T.cal = as.Date('2009-12-31'), T.tot = as.Date('2010-03-31'))



    } else {
      cbs <- NULL
    }

    # You want to return the object
    return(cbs) # access it via d()

  }) # you had wrong order of brackets ")}"

} # end function

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
One additional question: are you sure, that it will work on shiny server(like shinyapps.io)? I mean the problem with uploading data from PC